# ¿Cómo automatizar este diagrama de Gantt?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

¿Cómo puedo hacer para al poner las fechas en la columna de fecha de inicio y fecha de entrega, se representen en la tabla? que las celdas de todos los días involucrados se llenen para así hacer el diagrama de Gantt automatizado y no tener que poner manualmente la duración de cada tarea.

[image: google sheets diagrama de Gantt]

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar formato condicional o Google Apps Script para "llenar" las celdas.

Referencias

- [Usar reglas de formato condicional en Hojas de Cálculo de Google](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=es)
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets